# Infinite looping recursion in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

I am working on recursion in python and where the students are given difficulty levels and each difficulty has different points. For example if Students are given assignments of difficulty [4,4,6,6] and they get points of [20,20,30,30] separately. Now I need to calculate the total number of points that the class would get. I am using a dictionary, my process is correct when i input smaller inputs but when it comes to bigger inputs I am getting an error saying the program would be too long to execute, or my code for infinite loops. I'm using lambda to loop through the list and makes sure it only keeps those elements that returns true for the function.

```
import numpy as np

class Solution:
    def maxAssignmentPoints(self, difficulty, points, student) -> int:
        output = 0

   # assuming there is a 1:1 mapping between difficulty and points
        lookup = dict(zip(difficulty, points))

    # iterate through each student to get the maximum difficulty
        for s in student:
        # obtain max difficulty
            max_diff = max(list(filter(lambda x: x <= s, difficulty)))
            output += lookup[max_diff]
        return output


array1 = [int(x) for x in input().split(",")]
array2 = [int(x) for x in input().split(",")]
array3 = [int(x) for x in input().split(",")]

s= Solution()
print(s.maxAssignmentPoints(np.asarray(array1), np.asarray(array2), np.asarray(array3)))
```

I would really appreciate any help on this, and if you could point out my error(s). Thanks!

Comment: Why are you converting to `numpy` arrays and not using any `numpy` features? By doing so, you at best save a little memory, but add a ton of overhead converting between Python level types and `numpy` wrapped C level types. It should be possible to do stuff like finding the max below a bound with `numpy` features in ways that do less than 10% of the work, e.g. `max_diff` could be computed as `max_diff = difficulty[difficulty <= s].max()`.

Comment: Also, not sure where recursion fits in here; there is no recursion in this code.